# How do i exit runnable and switch another activity

Tags: java, android

I have a textview timer, i want it stops after 10 seconds of showing on display and after 10 seconds that my current activity jumps to an other activity

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while(Running)
            {
                try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                handler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        number+=1;
                        tvTimer.setText(String.valueOf(number)); //With setting value of number on textfield ITS POSSIBLE TO SEE THE TIMER
                        if(number==10)
                        {
                            Running = false;
                            handler.removeCallbacks(this);//that does not works for me to stop 

                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SonucMenu.class); 
                            startActivity(i); //Starting my second class

                        }
                    }

                });

            }

        }
```

My Second activity starts but the layout from second activity comes more than one time, what i want is that it comes only one time, and i think this problem depends on that i cant stop runnable

Here My Complete original Code
MainActivity.class

```
package com.marburg.leftright;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

import com.marburg.leftright.R;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 static Random rnd=new Random();
 static int rndN = rnd.nextInt(2);
 TextView inf,tvSc, tvTimer;
 Button btnL, btnR;
 int ScoreRhtg = 0;
 int ScoreFls  = 0;
 String right = "RIGHT";
 String left = "LEFT";
 private int number;
 private Handler handler;
 private boolean Running = true;
 MediaPlayer mySound;



   public void sendData()
{
 String rData = Integer.toString(ScoreRhtg); //Score Of Right Answer Data setting
 String wData = Integer.toString(ScoreFls);
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SonucMenu.class); 
 i.putExtra("DATA", rData);
 i.putExtra("DATA2", wData);
 startActivity(i);
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lr);

    Intent intent = getIntent(); //Get Intent from SonucMenu.class to turn back         MainActivity.java from New Button (This Class)
    inf = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
    btnL = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnL);
    btnR = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnR);
    tvSc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvScore);


     //Set text left or right according new random number
       if(rndN==1){
            inf.setText(right);
            }
            else
            {
                inf.setText(left);
            }



         //Set 0 for Left
    btnL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {   //Set 0 for Left
            if(rndN==0)
            {
            ScoreRhtg++;    
            tvSc.setText(ScoreRhtg+" Right");
            rndN=rnd.nextInt(2); //Renew the random number
            }
            else
            {
                ScoreFls++;
                tvSc.setText(ScoreFls+" False");
                rndN=rnd.nextInt(2); //Renew the random number
            }

            //Set text left or right according new random number
              if(rndN==1){
                    inf.setText(right);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        inf.setText(left);
                    }

            }
        });
    //Set 1 For Right
    btnR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(rndN==1)
             {
                 ScoreRhtg++;
                 tvSc.setText(ScoreRhtg+" Right");
                 rndN=rnd.nextInt(2); //Renew the random number
             }
             else
             {   
                 ScoreFls++;
                 tvSc.setText(ScoreFls+" False");
                 rndN=rnd.nextInt(2); //Renew the random number
             }

             //Set text left or right according a new random number 
             if(rndN==1){
                inf.setText(right);
                }
                else
                {
                    inf.setText(left);
                }

        }

     });



    //FOR TIMER RESPONSIBLE PART OF CODE

    tvTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
     handler = new Handler();

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
      {
         @Override
        public void run()
        {
             while(Running)
             {
                 try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
             }catch(InterruptedException e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
                handler.post(new Runnable()
                 {
                    @Override
                     public void run()
                     {
                         number+=1;
                        tvTimer.setText(String.valueOf(number)); //With setting  value   of number on textfield ITS POSSIBLE TO SEE THE TIMER
                         if(number==9)
                         {
                             mySound=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.click);
                            mySound.start();
                            Running = false;
                            handler.removeCallbacks(this);//Doesnt works for me
                             sendData();      //sendData function startActivity(i) included

                         }
                     }

                 });

            }

         }


     };
     new Thread(runnable).start();

     //END OF FOR TIMER RESPONSIBLE PART OF CODE

     }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And my Second Class SonucMenu.java

```
package com.example.timerdeneme2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SonucMenu extends MainActivity {


public TextView tvCorr, tvWro;
public Button btnNew, btnCls;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sonuc_menu);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle dataBundle = i.getExtras();
    String dataRString = dataBundle.getString("DATA");
    String dataWString = dataBundle.getString("DATA2");
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCorr);
    TextView tvW = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvWro);
    tv.setText(dataRString);
    tvW.setText(dataWString);

    btnNew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNew);
       btnNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SonucMenu.this, MainActivity.class);
                //myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
                SonucMenu.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
        });

       btnCls=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEx);

       btnCls.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
           android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
               System.exit(1);

           }
       });



}
}
```

And XML Layouts lr.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.marburg.leftright.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResCorr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvResCorr"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvResCorr" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnL"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="L"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnR"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="R"
            android:textSize="70dp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

 </TableLayout>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Info"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvScore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvInfo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Score"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTimer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Time" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And sonuc_menu.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.marburg.leftright.MainActivity" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResCorr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Correctness:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCorr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:text="X" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResWro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wrongness" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvWro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:text="X" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="113dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNew"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NEW" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BEST SCORES" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEx"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EXIT" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Runnable stops, when it reaches the last line of `run`. Which `run` method do you think does not stops and why?

Comment: I want when variable number (counter) stops when it is 10, that case is in my inner run method which starts with number+=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think for this you can use following code , It worked for me.**
It will start your activity after 10 seconds.

```
new Handler().postDelay(new Runnable() {          
@Override
public void run() {

Start Your activity here.

    }
}, 10000);
```

but one of the best solution will be (I just found it from develoer site):

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     strat your activity here.
 }
```

}.start();

Answer (score 0):

Use [View.post(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) and [View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)), no need to create additional thread.

```
private TextView tvTimer;
private final Runnable mCountDownRunnable = new Runnable() {
    private int mCount = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mCount++;
        if (mCount < 10) {
            tvTimer.setText(Integer.toString(mCount));
            tvTimer.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SonucMenu.class);
            YourActivity.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
};
```

to start runnable, call `tvTimer.post(mCountDownRunnable);`

Comment: this code looks good but while starting "            YourActivity.this.startActivity(i);" app shuts down

Comment: rename `YourActivity` with the class name of your activity.

Comment: That i have done too in my case MainActivity.this.startActivity(i); unfortunately it doesnt work :(

Comment: post logcat or more code, did you define runnable as a member of your activity? what about `SonucMenu`?

Comment: I posted complete original Code over

Comment: why `SonucMenu` extends `MainActivity`?

Comment: it was not an intention to do extends MainActivity, i used it before when i was challenging with multiactivity but now i know extends MainActivity is not useful, i must needed to add SonucMenu.java to AndroidManifest.xml, thank u for help